# What properties of a distribution uniquely define the distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

here's a pretty elementary stats question that I have yet to find a solid answer to online.

**What properties of a distribution uniquely define that distribution?**

I am pretty sure that the (1) PMF/PDF, (2) CDF, and (3) moment generating function for a distribution each uniquely define that distribution.

(i.e. if I know a distribution has PMF $\mathbb{P}(X=k) = {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$, then I can know for sure that this is the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$).

But are there any more properties of a distribution that would uniquely define it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Moments do not always identify the distribution uniquely, see [Hamburger moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem). [Cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) have a similar issue. In general, there are infinitely many "properties" that can identify the distribution, one can take any bijective map from measures to wherever and the image will be such a "property". Characteristic functions, Laplace transforms, and moments or cumulants in good cases, are images of just such maps. But there are other transforms, Mellin's for example.

Comment: The convolution with a fixed gaussian, ie. the distribution of $X+W$ with $W$ independent from $X$

Comment: @Conifold The hamburger moment problem concerns the existence of a distribution with a given sequence of moments. How does this relate to moments not identifying the distribution uniquely?

Comment: @Math1000 See uniqueness of solutions in the linked article.